# One of my friends can join my minecraft hamachi server but the other can't

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

My friend (call him friend1) and I can play my Hamachi server together no bother. When I asked my friend (call him friend2) if he wanted to join, he said yes. My friend (friend1) can play but the other one can't. We have tried everything, including port forwarding. This is really annoying and I don't want to 60 euro for a static IP!

Comment: can `friend2` connect to the VPN at all?

Comment: Yes he can connect

Comment: Is he whitelisted on the server? Can he ping it?

Comment: No he cant ping the server, it say connection timed out on his side and on my side. Friend1 went to his house and could play so the internet isn't the problem, to rule that out!

Comment: How about adding more details? Like operation systems.
We played yesterday between OSX, Win7 and Win8.1.
The last one is not fully working with the latest hamachi, but there is a fix batch file. Are you using Win8.1? Have you tried disabling his firewall? Have added TCP/IP protocol to the hamachi network?

Comment: Let your friend do a port scan, maybe some outgoing port is blocked by his firewall

Comment: It sounds like there is a firewall on friend2's computer or router that is blocking outgoing connections

Comment: @aman207 Non-corporate firewalls typically only block incoming connections, not outgoing ones.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft They can be configured to filter outgoing connections.

Answer (score 1):

So basically a lot of people have this problem, like lot's.
So this is what i'd do. maybe you'v done this but, might help!

First: Make sure all three of you have hamachi open. Then YOU have to make a new network on the same hamachi.

Second: After that give the details of the hamachi's address and password to all three of you.

Third: Check that the list of people on the hamachi. Should be only two people. Since as you can't see yourself.

Fourth: Start playing on the world, And open to lan. Then it should pop up on their server list. If not then get them to right click your account on hamachi and then they should click "get IPv4 address" (warning it might not say that i havn't used it in a while.) Make sure they don't click the IPv6. cause that isn't what they need. Other ways of doing this is by going into the cmd and doing "ip config" and looking for your ip. but that's harder...

That should work. Some things to do is check if your firewall is up. both be on the same version.

If that dosn't work then i can't think of much more to do other then:

Disable firewall.

Let friend1(or friend2) host.

restart your laptop. (Sometimes my internet stops working right and then i restart and it's all good.)

And if there is mods and the other player dosn't have it they can't connect.

Hmm... Just realized how big this post is. Awesome. Anyway hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

- Check your firewall settings.  If that does not work check to make
  sure that you do not have nine other people on your Hamachi network.
  Hamachi is limited to 10 people on the network.
- Check to make sure that you are on the same subnet as your friend.
- Also check to make sure that the games are the same version.
- Try posting some debug logs.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

if you have whitelist only the members on whitelist could join to put one member on whitelist /whitelist add [name] to remove a member /whitelist remove [name] I dont remember how to set on off the whitelist